# Displaying activity indicator to the right of tableview row

Tags: swift, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

My tableview is having Disclosure indicator as an accessory item. The `didSelectItem()` call of this tableview cell performs an api call on background. So the view will need to wait until the response to show next page. I have to provide an activity indicator to the position of disclosure indicator. how it is possible like in ios settings page

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    // Returns the cell value for each index
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: TenantCell.identifier, for: indexPath) as! TenantCell
    cell.populate(with: tenantList[indexPath.row])
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    Api.domain = tenantList[indexPath.row].url!
    sharedAFManager.getJsonData(api: Api.theme, completionHandler: { (response, statusCode) in
        if let theme = response {
            Api.logo = theme["logo"].stringValue
            Constants.passwordRegx = theme["passwordRegex"].stringValue
            self.performSegue(withIdentifier: Segue.login, sender: indexPath.row)
        }
    })
}


/// UITableview cell populating tenant informations
class TenantCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tenantImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenantNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenantUrlLabel: UILabel!

    func populate(with tenant: Tenant) {
        tenantNameLabel?.text = tenant.name
        tenantUrlLabel?.text = tenant.url
        tenantImage.image = UIImage(named: "breifcase")
    }
}
```

[image: Expected output]

Comment: where is `cellForRowAt` method code? plz upload your full code

Comment: Added `cellForRowAt `  method to the code sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please write in `cellForRowAt` Method :

```
cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
```

Then in `didSelectRowAt` Method please write

```
guard let cell : TenantCell = (tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! TenantCell) else {
        return
}
    cell.accessoryView = activityIndi
    activityIndi. startAnimating()
```

After geting the response

```
activityIndi. stopAnimating()
```

It may helps you. Thank you

Comment: Please press the up button for vote my answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Add Activity Indicator in `TableViewCell` As per your required

```
   class TenantCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var tenantImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenantNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var tenantUrlLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var activityIndi: UIActivityIndicatorView!

    func populate(with tenant: Tenant) {
        tenantNameLabel?.text = tenant.name
        tenantUrlLabel?.text = tenant.url
        tenantImage.image = UIImage(named: "breifcase")
        if tenant.isLoaderShow{
           activityIndi.startAnimating()
        }else{
           activityIndi.stopAnimating()
        }
```

Add one `Bool` Variable to your Tenant Model `isLoaderShow` and Change as per api completion and reload the `tableView` or reload `tableViewCell`

Comment: Sorry this doesn't full-fill my requirement. as i need to show the activity indicator in place of Disclosure indicator on loading like in my referral image

Comment: Sorry this doesn't full-fill my requirement. as i need to show the activity indicator in place of Disclosure indicator on loading.

Comment: Yes, you can achieve this using Hide and Show Disclosure indicator as per api completion

Answer (score 1):

- Place right Arrow image and activity indicator in your `tableviewCell` first. (Default 
  `right_Arrow_image.isHidden = false and indicator.isHidden = true` )
- in `didSelectRowAt` method hide `right_Arrow_image.isHidden = true` and `indicator.isHidden = false`
- Then call your `webservice` and after getting response Again set it as first step and move to the next screen